# Visual FoxPro - syntax error in Insert statement when using Entity Framework and OLEDB

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6, oledb, visual-foxpro

I need some help with Visual FoxPro syntax:

I am trying to execute the following query (actually composed by the .NET Entity Framework):

```
INSERT INTO 
  (SELECT 
Sname.Sn_Account, 
Sname.Sn_Name, 
Sname.Sn_Addr1, 
Sname.Sn_Addr2, 
Sname.Sn_Addr3, 
Sname.Sn_Addr4, 
Sname.Sn_Pstcode, 
Sname.Sn_Teleno, 
Sname.Sn_Faxno, 
Sname.Sn_Contact, 
Sname.Sn_Contac2, 
Sname.Sn_Region, 
Sname.Sn_Terrtry, 
Sname.Sn_Custype, 
Sname.Sn_Analsys, 
 CAST( Sname.Sn_Trnover AS n(20,2)) AS Sn_Trnover, 
Sname.Sn_Lastinv, 
Sname.Sn_Lastrec, 
 CAST( Sname.Sn_Currbal AS n(20,2)) AS Sn_Currbal, 
Sname.Sn_Crlim, 
 CAST( Sname.Sn_Ordrbal AS n(20,2)) AS Sn_Ordrbal, 
Sname.Sn_Stmntac, 
Sname.Sn_Invceac, 
Sname.Sn_Priorty, 
Sname.Sn_Stop, 
Sname.Sn_Acknow, 
Sname.Sn_Nextpay, 
Sname.Sn_Delinst, 
Sname.Sn_Memo, 
Sname.Sn_Dwar, 
Sname.Sn_Desp, 
Sname.Sn_Route, 
Sname.Sn_Tprfl, 
Sname.Sn_Cprfl, 
Sname.Sn_Ctry, 
Sname.Sn_Nrthire, 
Sname.Sn_Vrn, 
Sname.Sn_Delt, 
Sname.Sn_Ntrn, 
Sname.Sn_Mtrn, 
Sname.Sn_Dl_Flag, 
Sname.Sn_Dl_Date, 
Sname.Sn_Branch, 
Sname.Sn_Model, 
Sname.Sn_Lupdate, 
Sname.Sn_Sana, 
Sname.Sn_Rana, 
Sname.Sn_Vendor, 
Sname.Sn_Custloc, 
Sname.Sn_Bana, 
Sname.Sn_Key1, 
Sname.Sn_Key2, 
Sname.Sn_Key3, 
Sname.Sn_Key4, 
Sname.Sn_Bankac, 
Sname.Sn_Banksor, 
Sname.Sn_Email, 
Sname.Sn_Wwwpage, 
Sname.Sn_Fcreate, 
Sname.Sn_Epasswd, 
Sname.Sn_Estore, 
Sname.Sn_Luptime, 
Sname.Sn_Trndate, 
Sname.Sn_Atpycd, 
Sname.Sn_Dormant, 
Sname.Sn_Ordmail, 
Sname.Sn_Emailst, 
Sname.Sn_Emailoa, 
Sname.Sn_Project, 
Sname.Sn_Job, 
Sname.Sn_Docmail, 
Sname.Sn_Cldate, 
Sname.Sn_Cmgroup, 
Sname.Sn_Crdchck, 
Sname.Sn_Crdcrno, 
Sname.Sn_Crdnotes, 
Sname.Sn_Crdrate, 
Sname.Sn_Crdscor, 
Sname.Sn_Bic, 
Sname.Sn_Iban, 
Sname.Sn_Dltmail, 
Sname.Sn_Dl_Pubid, 
Sname.Sn_Sepayee, 
Sname.Sn_Adjsvcd, 
Sname.Sn_Ovravmt, 
Sname.Sn_Sgrp
FROM Sname Sname)(Sn_Account, Sn_Name, Sn_Addr1, Sn_Addr2, Sn_Addr3, Sn_Addr4, Sn_Pstcode, Sn_Teleno, Sn_Faxno, Sn_Contact, Sn_Contac2, Sn_Region, Sn_Terrtry, Sn_Custype, Sn_Analsys, Sn_Trnover, Sn_Lastinv, Sn_Lastrec, Sn_Currbal, Sn_Crlim, Sn_Ordrbal, Sn_Stmntac, Sn_Invceac, Sn_Priorty, Sn_Stop, Sn_Acknow, Sn_Nextpay, Sn_Delinst, Sn_Memo, Sn_Dwar, Sn_Desp, Sn_Route, Sn_Tprfl, Sn_Cprfl, Sn_Ctry, Sn_Nrthire, Sn_Vrn, Sn_Delt, Sn_Ntrn, Sn_Mtrn, Sn_Dl_Flag, Sn_Dl_Date, Sn_Branch, Sn_Model, Sn_Lupdate, Sn_Sana, Sn_Rana, Sn_Vendor, Sn_Custloc, Sn_Bana, Sn_Key1, Sn_Key2, Sn_Key3, Sn_Key4, Sn_Bankac, Sn_Banksor, Sn_Email, Sn_Wwwpage, Sn_Fcreate, Sn_Epasswd, Sn_Estore, Sn_Luptime, Sn_Trndate, Sn_Atpycd, Sn_Dormant, Sn_Ordmail, Sn_Emailst, Sn_Emailoa, Sn_Project, Sn_Job, Sn_Docmail, Sn_Cldate, Sn_Cmgroup, Sn_Crdchck, Sn_Crdcrno, Sn_Crdnotes, Sn_Crdrate, Sn_Crdscor, Sn_Bic, Sn_Iban, Sn_Dltmail, Sn_Dl_Pubid, Sn_Sepayee, Sn_Adjsvcd, Sn_Ovravmt, Sn_Sgrp)
  values (@__C2P__1, @__C2P__2, @__C2P__3, @__C2P__4, @__C2P__5, @__C2P__6, @__C2P__7, @__C2P__8, @__C2P__9, @__C2P__10, @__C2P__11, @__C2P__12, @__C2P__13, @__C2P__14, @__C2P__15, @__C2P__16, CTOT('2017-05-27T13:04:49'), CTOT('2017-05-27T13:04:49'), @__C2P__17, @__C2P__18, @__C2P__19, @__C2P__20, @__C2P__21, @__C2P__22, .f., .f., @__C2P__23, @__C2P__24, @__C2P__25, @__C2P__26, @__C2P__27, @__C2P__28, @__C2P__29, @__C2P__30, @__C2P__31, .f., @__C2P__32, @__C2P__33, @__C2P__34, @__C2P__35, @__C2P__36, CTOT('2017-05-27T13:04:49'), .f., .f., CTOT('2017-05-27T13:04:49'), @__C2P__37, @__C2P__38, @__C2P__39, @__C2P__40, @__C2P__41, @__C2P__42, @__C2P__43, @__C2P__44, @__C2P__45, @__C2P__46, @__C2P__47, @__C2P__48, @__C2P__49, CTOT('2017-05-27T00:00:00'), @__C2P__50, @__C2P__51, @__C2P__52, CTOT('2017-05-27T13:04:49'), @__C2P__53, .f., @__C2P__54, .t., .f., @__C2P__55, @__C2P__56, 0, CTOT('2017-05-27T13:04:49'), @__C2P__57, CTOT('2017-05-27T13:04:49'), @__C2P__58, @__C2P__59, @__C2P__60, @__C2P__61, @__C2P__62, @__C2P__63, .f., @__C2P__64, @__C2P__65, @__C2P__66, @__C2P__67, @__C2P__68)
```

The error I am getting is:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException : An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
  ----> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException : An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
  ----> VfpClient.VfpException : Syntax error.
  ----> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException : Syntax error.
```

In inner-most exception speaks of a syntax error somewhere in the SQL statement.

Are there any Visual FoxPro wizards who could tell me where in this statement is a syntax error?

Comment: Just found another post using Related section, which could be my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386352/sql-parametrized-syntax-error-with-vfp-oledb

Comment: The link you provided really doesn't apply in this case because the VFP EF provider uses a wrapper class that can work with named parameters.  https://randomdevnotes.com/2013/06/02/using-named-parameters-when-accessing-visual-foxpro-data-from-net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your EDMX file essentially has the table configured as "readonly" which is why you are seeing an insert statement that is generated with a select statement instead of a table name.  See this [issue](https://github.com/tombrothers/VfpEntityFrameworkProvider2/issues/4#issuecomment-192884664) for more details.

Comment: Tom, many thanks for your response and support. Since I am not at liberty to change the VFP schema, and due to complexity of the schema, I would prefer to go with the option "Modify the EDMX file so that the Entity is not read only."  Per advice in your blog, I got a copy of Programming Entity Framework by Julia Lerman, and also Programming Entity Framework DB Context by the same author. Might you be able to point me to the chapter/pages which would educate me on editing the EDMX file directly?